# fprintf(long) writes 8 bytes and fscanf(long) reads 6 bytes why?

Tags: c, file, compression, huffman-code

I'm writing a Huffman algorithm and when I write my file header, I store the length of my file because there will be some spare bits and I need to know where to stop.

This happens instead when I write the length of my file: It writes 8 bytes, but when I read, it reads only 6.

```
long totChar;
long size;

fprintf(outfile, "%ld", totChar);

fscanf(cmpfile, "%ld", &size);
```

I'm sure that works because if I add for example:

```
fgetc(cmpfile); \\compressed file
fgetc(cmpfile);
```

and then I start reading, the decompression is successful.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: what is it writing and what is it reading? I don't get how you've concluded that.

Answer (score 1):

You're reading and writing characters, not binary.

For example, maybe when you write data, you write the number 57,843,249 (8 digits).  But when you read data, you read 875,345 (6 digits).